# A proof of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality using Jensen's inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities

A brief look at the statement of [Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality) would suggest that there should exist a proof by a clever use of Jensen's inequality. In other words, there should be a function of the form $$F(a-b/n)=\|D^b f\|_a$$ such that $\log F(a-b/n)$ is convex. That would provide a short proof of the inequality. The existing proofs that I could find on the internet involved complicated double inductions, etc. Is anyone aware of a proof along these lines? Thanks!

Comment: The shortest proof I know of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequalities in full generality uses Besov spaces and their characterization in terms of the Littlewood-Paley (LP) decomposition. No induction argument in the indices is needed there, and the LP decompostion makes the interpolation parameter $\theta$ quite evident in the course of the proof. See e.g. Theorem 2.44, pp. 84-85 of the book *Fourier Analysis and Nonilinear Partial Differential Equations* by H. Bahouri, J.-Y. Chemin and R. Danchin (Springer-Verlag, 2011).